# What bird / animal has this call?

Tags: species-identification

USA MA NE

I have a bird / animal coming to the trees in the backyard making this call (see link to audio file), which does not really sound like a bird - it's fairly low frequency. I have not seen it. Sometimes it sits in a young tree, where you can almost see through to the trunk. But I cannot make it out, so it's not very big (like a turkey). It comes at late afternoon and stays around until ~11PM. It switches trees fairly quickly, so I assume it can fly. The call is always the same. Sometimes another one of its kind answers.

[Bird_animal_call_mp3](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2fzkw0ovd8oeplm/My_recording_1_cut.mp3?dl=0)

You don't need dropbox. Ignore "suspicious link". Close login popup. Click download arrow. Direct download.

I added a Soundcloud link:

[Bird_animal_call_mp3](https://soundcloud.com/user-957875636/my-recording-1-cut/s-rXzvY4wWFig)

Comment: No idea about US bird species, but it sounds similar to a European magpie. Compare with https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kz4SvP0c_VE

Comment: Surely you can find a way to share an audio file that doesn't require people to ignore a "suspicious link" warning and download a file from your dropbox.

Comment: @csk, well do you have a suggestion where to upload it? You can check the url and the file on virustotal.

Comment: YouTube. iNaturalist (although that requires a login, so it's also limiting). Other options are listed and discussed here: https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-best-websites-for-audio-file-uploading-and-sharing.

Comment: I added a Soundcloud link.

Comment: Sounds a lot like a woodpecker to me. Which one, I don't know, not being familiar enough with the variety in the USA, but I think the Red-bellied might be similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a grey tree frog's mating call. See youtube link:

[Grey tree frog mating call](https://youtu.be/9bzotS1ow0Q)

Source for finding the answer: Audubon Society